# Using CSS ellipsis with other elements on same line(compatible with ie9)

Tags: css

```
<div class='box'>
    <p class='text'>long text<p>
    <div class="icon"></div>
</div>

.box {
    width: 175px;
}
.icon {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: red;
}
```

how to achieve whether .text is ellipsised or not, .icon should come after .text in the same line?

thanks

Comment: seriously, you want it for IE9 ??

Comment: Check if this is useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26967630/rendering-issue-of-text-overflow-ellipsis-in-ie9?rq=1